# CDNが落ちているとき、ファイルの読み込み自体を止める方法はありますか？

Tags: html

現在、下記で読み込んでいますが、例えばfontawesomeが落ちている時には読み込み自体を止める、ような書き方をすることは可能ですか？

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxx.js" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
```

Comment: 止める、とはどういう状態なのかわかりませんでした。読み込めないことには変わりないと思うのですが。

Comment: むやみに長い文章も困りますが、re9 さんの場合は "質問の背景" を含めた方がいいのかなと思います。 / [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) における **問題を紹介する** が欠けている気がします。

Comment: 一定期間経過しても正常に読み込めない場合は、読み込み自体を回避する方法はないかと思い質問しました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問の内容そのままを実現するならPHPなどを用いて事前に相手先の生死確認を行って出力を変える方法が考えられますが、"コンテンツ(の一部)が読めないから諦める" はユーザー視点でフレンドリーではない対応に思えます。

CDNサーバの生死に左右されずに利用できるよう、必要なファイルを自サイトで管理することも検討してみてください。

パフォーマンスなどを考えてCDNを優先したいのであれば、まずCDNを参照した後にローカル(自サイト)のファイルを読みに行く **フォールバック** という手法があるようです。
下記はjQueryでの記述例ですが、Font Awesomeでも応用できるでしょう。

**参考:**
[CDNサーバに不具合があった場合にjQueryの読み込みをフォールバックする](https://blanche-toile.com/web/jquery-cdn-fallback)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"><\/script>');</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

主語がはっきりしないし「落ちている」の定義がないのでどう書いていいかわからないですが

- Web UA が当該 `script` を受信した際 Web UA 側がリンク先の生死判断をし読む読まないを選択したい

無理っす。 Web UA がリンク先の生死判断をできるとしたら、リンク先スクリプトを読みに行って読めなかったら死んでいる、ですから。

- Web Server が事前にリンク先の生死判断をし、閲覧者のアクセスの際、当該 `<script src=...>` を生成しない

それであなたの/広告元の/依頼者の/閲覧者の要求を達することができますか？　これも「生死判断」の定義次第でしょう。まあ普通はやらない・やる意味がないです。